# cant use jquery dependant libraries inside the js function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a js function which is

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function adjustSpinnerOptionsAccordingToRadioBox(spinnerId, optionsArray) {

      //clear the spinner
      $(spinnerId).html('');
      //load the new options
      for (data of optionsArray) {
         $(spinnerId).append($('<option/>', { 
            value: data.value,
            text : data.value 
        }));
      }

      $('#patient_selector').editableSelect({filter: false });



    }
}
```

whenever i try to call .editableSelect inside the jquery scope, it throws an error

```
$(...).editableSelect is not a function
```

But when i call the same line of code outside the function it works, what is the reason behind it?

editableSelect is a jquery based library (http://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/)

Comment: I don't think its a outside/inside the function discussion. You should check if you call this Jquery function only when the dom element that its working on was already loaded.

Comment: Try putting the whole thing inside a `$(function() {...})` statement (jQuery short `$(document).ready()`).

Comment: its already inside document.ready method

Comment: i cant us .editableSelect inside document.ready, it throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

Check if patient_selector element is loaded before calling 
editableSelect function.